# In Unity unable to find second github branch

Tags: unity, git

I'm using github for unity asset and for some reason I can't find new branch that was created on a different PC.
I tried refreshing, fetching, reinstalling asset, reinstalling asset and recloning repository.

Strangely, my laptop shows the branch, but not my personal home computer.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Have you pushed the branch to the remote repository after creating it ? I sometimes forgot to do this as well. :)

Comment: It's pushed. You can see all files on github site

Comment: I can access this branch on friends laptop and my own laptop. But i can't reach it on my PC

Comment: Have you tried only with the Unity asset ? Can you try to fetch the repo with command line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your project root folder in a command line and try this :

```
git branch -r
```

To view all available branches on remote.

```
git checkout --track origin/remote_branch_name
```

To checkout the branch and track it from the remote repository.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537392/git-fetch-remote-branch) for more details.

Comment: Where can i paypal you? :D Love you! It works just fine now!

Comment: Fine for this time, next time it will cost much more haha. Welcome to StackExchange community ! Have a great time here and good luck with your projects :)

Comment: @Tadas Folks here are rewarded with Internet points: along with accepting the answer, like you already have, you can also upvote it :)

Comment: Cheers! I'm not new on stack tho. I know how system works. :P Can't upvote yet, because I don't have enough points for it. Will get back when i'll have enough. Thanks once again, you saved me so much time for our project ;)